# .Net RAD IDE - Opensource Preferred

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2008

I am looking for a tool that would allow me to use LINQ and build a .Net app rapidly.

Comment: In your tag there - `visual studio`

Comment: When people say Open Source they usually mean free... Try Visual Studio Express (Free) Edition.

Answer (score 2):

If you must have an open-source .NET IDE, you have two choices that I'm aware of: [MonoDevelop](http://monodevelop.com/) and [SharpDevelop](http://www.icsharpcode.net/opensource/sd/). However, there are also free versions of Visual Studio.

Answer (score 2):

If you need **open source** IDEs

Check :

- [SharpDevelop](http://www.icsharpcode.net/opensource/sd/)
- [CSharp Studio](http://csharp-studio.sourceforge.net/)
- [MonoDevelop](http://monodevelop.com/)
- [xacc](http://xacc.wordpress.com/)

Answer (score 1):

The tool is called Visual Studio. There's even a [free version](http://www.microsoft.com/express/downloads/). Another tool might be hiring a developer that builds .NET applications rapidly.

Comment: Neither of your solutions is open source - not VS, and also not the human genome.