# IS there any open source Web based IDE for .net

Tags: .net, ide

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Online .NET IDE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422035/online-net-ide)

any free open source Web based IDE available for .net. if anyone knows about it then please share the info with me.

Comment: The question is surely a duplicate question, but the link is not a good example. It is for free IDEs, not open source, a big distinction.

Comment: When you say "web-based", I assume you mean "works in a web-browser". Is this correct?

Comment: [Koding](https://koding.com/?c=ideh) is browser based, supports .NET via Mono, but only the Editor (Ace editor) is open source, not the whole platform specifically. Let me know if that helps :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Visual Studio Express](http://www.microsoft.com/express/) is free but it's limited and not open source. It works fine for most practical purposes and it does come bundled with the Microsoft compiler so it's an easy to use end-to-end solution.

[Notepad++](http://sourceforge.net/projects/notepad-plus) has support for C# and it's handy to use for text editing purposes. For more fledged environments, [SharpDevelop](http://www.icsharpcode.net/opensource/sd) is another IDE that comes to mind. Neither of these IDEs has a built-in compiler, so as with any IDE you still need a compiler.

See the related question for a more comprehensive list of IDEs: [.Net RAD IDE - Opensource Preferred](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3311754/net-rad-ide-opensource-preferred) or http://www.csharptools.com/ for related tools.

Comment: None of these is web based....